# The mathematics of tavern puzzles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I remember seeing a paper on the arxiv this year (which I cannot now find Edit: This paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6545, found by j.c.) proposing to study the linkage of rigid bodies such as tavern or carnival puzzles. However, they only worked out one simple example (like showing that two circles of the same diameter can't pass through each other).

This is an interesting idea which I'd like to see more about. I know that such ideas have been studied in symplectic geometry (e.g. the symplectic camel).

It would help to examine a relatively simple case. So my question is:

Given $n$ circles of equal radius in 3-space, how many distinct linkages are there? I.e. how many configuration are there which cannot be made the same by isotopies of 3-space which restrict to a family of isometries on the circles?

I would also accept a solution for $n\leq 4$.

Comment: I do not know enough geometry to tell if "right" and "left" handed arrangements of three mutually linked circles (Borromean rings?) are identified or not.  Could you tell me if they are?

Comment: In knot theory, at least, the jury is out. Some tables of knots include mirror images as distinct knots, some do not.

Comment: Although, someone has shown that the Borromean rings cannot be circles, which is one reason I find this interesting.

Comment: I think they can be identical ellipses though.  Also, there are chiral versions of another three ring linkage, which I would like to know if they are identified.

Comment: For purposes of this question, I would consider them to be separate, as they cannot be isotoped, one into the other.

Comment: There is some discussion on this page http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/borromeo.html . Also you may find the dissertation of Genevieve Walsh interesting http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gwalsh/dissertationfinal.pdf ; she studies great circle links in the 3-sphere, and classifies them up to 5 components.

Comment: OK. Sorry to beat this to death, but I want to make sure I understand.  For this question, reflections in R^3 are disallowed for identification purposes. If I have that wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Reflections are not allowed, just like vampires.

Comment: The following may help: "The theorem stating Borromean rings to be impossible with flat circles is proved rigorously in the article "Borromean circles are impossible," Amer. Math. Monthly, 98 (1991) 340-341, by B.Lindström and H.-O. Zetterström." That is a quote from the wedsite: http://www.popmath.org.uk/sculpmath/pagesm/borings.html.

Comment: I like this question because I've always wondered.  I got some flak from a friend in college when I explained that I was trying to find a topological solution to such a puzzle as inspiration.  They're of course topologically trivial, but the point was to stay as close to rigid as possible and then try to imitate the motions with the actual puzzle.

Comment: Was it perhaps this arxiv paper? http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6545

Comment: Yes, that is the paper.

Answer (score 2):

A general useful theory probably does not exist. The reason is that even in dimension $n=2$, and even if all but one of the the bodies are rectangles, the problem is PSPACE-hard. That is because a popular [board game Rush Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_%28board_game%29) is PSPACE-complete. This a [result of Flake and Baum](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.4713).

By taking a product with an interval, and enclosing the puzzle in a box, one can of course transfer the result to three (and also higher) dimensions.